# Selenium WebDriver - Dropbox selection Java

Tags: java, drop-down-menu, selenium-webdriver

**Hi all**

Sorry for any problems. I'm new in WebDriver so i would be great full for any help
If you have any goo tutorial, which i can use thank you for that.

So lets get into my problem:

I have got a dropbox and a try to pick every value and confirm that with button then get a warning message ....

**Here is my code:**

```
public void specialniBudovyVsechny() throws IOException{
        try{
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='budovy']/a")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='main']/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td/strong[2]/a")).click();    
            Select listItem=new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='main']/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/select")));
            String[] dropdown = new String[listItem.getOptions().size()];
            WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='main']/p"));
                for(int i=0;i<listItem.getOptions().size();i++)
                {
                   listItem.selectByIndex(i);   
                   dropdown[i]  = listItem.getFirstSelectedOption().getText();
                }


                for(int a = 0;a<dropdown.length ;a++){
                    if(a == 0 | a == 1 | a == 12 | a == 13){
                        listItem.selectByVisibleText(dropdown[a]);
                        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='main']/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/input")).click();
                        Assert.assertEquals(element.getText(), "Nemáš žádnou rozestavěnou budovu"); 
                    }
                    else{
                        listItem.selectByVisibleText(dropdown[a]);
                        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='main']/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/input")).click();
                        Assert.assertEquals(element.getText(), "Tvá rozestavěná budova: "+dropdown[a]+" - 0%");

                    } }     }
        catch (Exception vyjimka){
            getScreenShot();
            System.out.println("SpecialniBudovyVsechny");
            System.out.println(vyjimka);
            }
```

**Everytime i gets this error:**
org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up
Command duration or timeout: 11 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html
Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:55:52'
System info: host: 'N0119', ip: '192.168.0.14', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_65'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false, handlesAlerts=true, databaseEnabled=true, version=41.0.2, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=false, acceptSslCerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true, locationContextEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 8634cbaf-70db-4b07-a19f-b040ba5c60bd

**I found out that the issue is array but i dont know how to solve that. If i place right array for example dropdown[2]. It works**

Thank you

Comment: Please format your post to be more readable

Comment: Done. Sorry for that it was my first post.

Answer (score 0):

As a suggestion you can try to put this:

```
Select listItem=new Select(...
```

inside your loops.

Comment: Thank you unfortunately it doesn't help. First loop is ok the problem is for(int a = 0;a<dropdown.length ;a++){
                    if(a == 0 | a == 1 | a == 12 | a == 13){
                       **listItem.selectByVisibleText(dropdown[a]);**  If i print array it has right text which should be set for visible set but it fails. if i give value into dropdown for example: dropdown[3] it set it right.

Comment: Probably first call to

    .click()

makes this xpath

    By.xpath("//*[@id='main']/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/select")

invalid. 
I suggest you to check your javascript code.

Comment: I think you are right. Unfortunately, i can not check it. I'm just learning selenium and i'm not doing that on my own websites. Do you have any idea how to solve the issue. I tried to place timeout but i doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned up your code a bit. There were a few issues. I think I got it put back together correctly but I have no way to test it.

1. You were storing all the `OPTION` values in a string array and then looping through the array. There's no need to do that... you can just loop through the options and compare the text as you go. Saves you having to loop through twice.
2. In your `if..else` you were executing the same two lines of code in both branches. To clean this up, just pull those two lines before the `if..then` to prevent redundancy.
3. You were using `|` instead of `||`. I think you meant to use logical `OR` which is `||`. See [this page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) for more info.

Here's the cleaned up code. Give this a try and let me know if you run into any issues.

```
public void specialniBudovyVsechny() throws IOException
{
    try
    {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='budovy']/a")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='main']/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td/strong[2]/a")).click();
        Select listItem = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='main']/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/select")));
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='main']/p"));

        for (int a = 0; a < listItem.getOptions().size(); a++)
        {
            listItem.selectByIndex(a);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='main']/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/input")).click();
            if (a == 0 || a == 1 || a == 12 || a == 13)
            {
                Assert.assertEquals(element.getText(), "Nemáš žádnou rozestavěnou budovu");
            }
            else
            {
                Assert.assertEquals(element.getText(), "Tvá rozestavěná budova: " + listItem.getFirstSelectedOption().getText() + " - 0%");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception vyjimka)
    {
        getScreenShot();
        System.out.println("SpecialniBudovyVsechny");
        System.out.println(vyjimka);
    }
}
```